# android studio 1.2.1 fails to install on mac

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Android studio 1.2.1 fails to install on MAC system.

The JDK is installed. When Android studio starts up for the first time, I get the following set of error messages.

> java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Argument for @NotNull parameter 'name' of com/android/tools/idea/welcome/Platform. must not be null
>           at com.intellij.idea.IdeaApplication.run(IdeaApplication.java:178)
>           at com.intellij.idea.MainImpl$1$1$1.run(MainImpl.java:52)
>           at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:311)
>           at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:749)
>           at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)
>           at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:702)
>           at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:696)
>           at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>           at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:75)
>           at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:719)
>           at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:362)
>           at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
>           at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
>           at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
>           at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
>           at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
>           at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
>       Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Argument for @NotNull parameter 'name' of com/android/tools/idea/welcome/Platform. must not be null
>           at com.android.tools.idea.welcome.Platform.(Platform.java)
>           at com.android.tools.idea.welcome.Platform.getLatestPlatform(Platform.java:72)
>           at com.android.tools.idea.welcome.Platform.createSubtree(Platform.java:89)
>           at com.android.tools.idea.welcome.InstallComponentsPath.createComponentTree(InstallComponentsPath.java:81)
>           at com.android.tools.idea.welcome.InstallComponentsPath.init(InstallComponentsPath.java:215)
>           at com.android.tools.idea.wizard.DynamicWizardPath.attachToWizard(DynamicWizardPath.java:97)
>           at com.android.tools.idea.wizard.DynamicWizard.addPath(DynamicWizard.java:233)
>           at com.android.tools.idea.welcome.FirstRunWizard.init(FirstRunWizard.java:75)
>           at com.android.tools.idea.welcome.FirstRunWizardHost.setupWizard(FirstRunWizardHost.java:100)
>           at com.android.tools.idea.welcome.FirstRunWizardHost.getWelcomePanel(FirstRunWizardHost.java:92)
>           at com.intellij.openapi.wm.impl.welcomeScreen.WelcomeFrame.(WelcomeFrame.java:68)
>           at com.intellij.openapi.wm.impl.welcomeScreen.WelcomeFrame.showNow(WelcomeFrame.java:173)
>           at com.intellij.idea.IdeaApplication$IdeStarter.main(IdeaApplication.java:302)
>           at com.intellij.idea.IdeaApplication.run(IdeaApplication.java:172)
>           ... 16 more

What could be the reason for this? Any solutions for the same?

Comment: Duplicate..Turn off internet and start the IDE

Comment: I would like to point out there is a version 1.4 that you should install instead